# Is Playerprefs Accessible inside the Scene itself only?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to access my PlayerPref created on the Scene "Main menu" and I'm trying to access it in the Scene "Level 1-1" It's not working. I've tried debugging the problems and this is my only Conclusion. I cannot access Playerprefs from other Scene

Answer (score 3):

There's a good chance that you're not committing the changes you made to PlayerPrefs. You can do this using [PlayerPrefs.Save](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html).

The whole idea of PlayerPrefs is that it's persistent, between scenes and sessions. You should undoubtedly be able to access PlayerPrefs from any scene provided, of course, you're saving it, and obviously if you're using the same key.

Comment: Thanks A ton! I just realized playerprefs is Case sensitive.